# Zapier Cli - Setting choices on outputFields does show value, not displaytext

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

I have an outputField "mchoice2". This is the definition of the outputField:

```
[{"label":"mchoice2","choices":{"m":"Mac OS","w":"Windows 10"},
"type":"text","key":"mchoice2","required":false,"help_text":""}]
```

My request returns:

```
{ mchoice2: 'm' }
```

But UI shows an "m" instead of "Mac OS". Is it normal behaviour or is there anything wrong in my definition?

[image: image showing zapier ui]

Answer (score 1):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

That's working as intended. As [the schema](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-schema/blob/master/docs/build/schema.md#fieldchoicesschema) notes, `choices` is a map of **value** to **label**. So while users see `Mac OS` (which, as a total pedantic sidenote, should be `macOS`), the value that comes through in later steps is `m`. You can reverse these or set it up differently depending on the type of behavior you want.

​Let me know if you've got any other questions!